# Can I make Nautilus look better in Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: nautilus, themes, lubuntu, appearance, filemanager

I mean that PCManFM and Thunar follow my theme:

[image]

[image]

Nautilus does not:

[image]

I have to add that I do not want to change my present theme. And I guess that is the problem, as it does not have a gtk3 folder included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus is gtk3. Thunar is gtk2. I don't know about the third. Ensure that the theme you use has a gtk-3.0 folder if you want Nautilus to be styled as well.
Your theme may be in `~/.themes` or in `/usr/share/themes` (which is where they're located in Ubuntu 12.04.)
The **Ambiance** theme, for example, is here: `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance`. Within are the following:

> [03:04 PM] /usr/share/themes/Ambiance $ ls
>
> **gtk-2.0**  **gtk-3.0**  index.theme  **metacity-1**  **unity**

The presence of the **gtk-3.0** folder ensures that apps based on gtk3 will be styled correctly.

Edit: I suspect that most software from GNOME will be gtk3. Other things like Chrome, Firefox, LibreOffice still are gtk2.

Anyway, as the other answer also suggested:

**Nautilus is gtk3: use a gtk3 theme if you want a gtk3 program to be themed**.

(In order to use a theme that does not have gtk3 support: a not very recommendable workaround is to copy the gtk3 folder from a theme that has it into the folder of the one that does not. In fact, in Lubuntu, one can extract and copy themes in home/username/.themes in order to install them, a location which does not require root privilege. But some applications like Synaptic Manager require a theme in `usr/share/themes`: see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/184683/47206) question.)

Comment: I am in Lubuntu (LXDE), not Gnome. The theme I use (Elegant Arch, a blue variation of Elegant Brit theme) does not contain the gtk3 folder. copying that from Ambiance for example would give what result do you imagine?

Comment: i should mark as definitive your answer, i hope you don't mind if I edit it a bit. the other answer says the same with less explanations. i have tried moving a gtk3 directory from a different theme into mine and it themes Nautilus and other gtk3 based apps like Audacious. But that is not an answer, just a variation of the main answer, which now is clear:  `use a gtk3 theme if you want a gtk3 program to be themed`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to *Preferences* → *Customize Look and Feel* from the menu
2. Change the theme to `Lubuntu-default` in **widget** tab. It will make nautilus to look good and compatible with other Lubuntu apps

#### Response to latest updates of requirements by OP

If you don't want to change your theme, I fear it is not possible to workaround this. Because, nautilus version 3.0 or greater requires gtk-3 themes, which your currently active theme surely is not supporting.

If you really want to have nautilus to be compatible with the installed theme, I would suggest you to contact theme developer for a request to implement gtk-3 theme in this one. If you are good with css and javascript and feel interested, I think you may yourself try to implement the theme in gtk-3. See [this themeing guide](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/theming.html) for help.

Comment: thnx but that is what i want: to keep my theme. edited question accordingly.

Comment: @cipricus i've responsed to your latest updated question. See the updated part of my answer. thanks :)

Comment: thnx, but as you can see some workaround was my solution, and i have added it as edit to the other answer: adding gtk3 directory in the main directory of the theme. even better, related versions of my favourite theme now have gtk3 versions. i am not good at editing themes: so I have a new question: http://askubuntu.com/q/184758/47206