# How can I theme Synaptic Manager?

Tags: themes, lubuntu, synaptic, gtk3, gtk-2

I use **Lubuntu 12.04** and a gtk2 theme, *[Elegant Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111040)*.

With such a theme, gtk2 applications like Thunar will be themed, while others like Nautilus, would be not (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/184650/47206) ant the images there).

Because I wanted to theme gtk3 applications like Nautilus, Audacious etc., I have copied the "gtk-3" folder from the main folder of a gtk3 theme into the main folder of my *Elegant arch* theme, which is in home/username/themes. Using the gtk3 folder from this *[full flat](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/full+flat?content=152100)* theme I got a pretty similar look in gtk2 and gtk 3 apps.

Lubuntu Desktop Center, Ubuntu Desktop Center, Network Options and other such apps are now themed (before they were not). Even Update Manager is.

[image]

But why is **Synaptic Manager** not themed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Synaptic Manager is a gtk2 application. So, all this has nothing to do with theming gtk3 apps.

But **in order to use a theme for Synaptic, that theme has to be put in `/usr/share/themes`**.

I figured where to put the theme by the fact that the *lubuntu-default* theme, which has gtk2+3 support and had themed Synaptic, was in `/usr/share/themes`, while *Elegant Arch* theme was in `~/.themes`. Also, Synaptic uses gtk2: when I put *Elegant Arch* theme (with the gtk3 folder of the *full flat* theme inside) into `/usr/share/themes`, Synaptic takes the theming of *Elegant Arch*.

Answer (score 7):

The application you are opening is one that needs ***root***  privileges. You could also link the files to use them:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.themes /root/.themes
sudo ln -s ~/.icons /root/.icons
sudo ln -s ~/.fonts /root/.fonts
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using LXAppearance to change themes on i3wm. You have to open LXAppearance as root and apply a theme to change the theme of applications that run as root.

This will change that ugly Raleigh theme that the Synaptic Package Manager is using.